# Confusion about System.Data.SQLite.dll

Tags: database, linux, mono, sqlite

The site, http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/, talks about a mixed-mode assembly and a managed-only version of the provider.  Are they both named System.Data.SQLite.dll?  I installed the managed-only version in windows and it is working.  Which, as I understand it, means that I must also have the native sqlite3.dll file somewhere on my machine that it is finding, right?

When I try to get my assembly to run on Linux with Mono, I get an EntryPointNotFoundException looking for sqlite3_open_v2.  So I downloaded the precompiled shared-library for Linux without the TCL bindings from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and placed it in the same folder as the other assemblies.  But that didn't change anything.

The page at http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries says Linux will look at my LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  So I set that to contain '.', the current directory.  That didn't work either.

So then I copied sqlite-3.6.19.so to sqlite-3.so, sqlite3.so and sqlite.so.  Still no change.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide the full error message, and run your program like this:

MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono app.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using System.Data.SQLite.dll on Windows and Linux, I decided to use Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll on both sides.

Comment: And I think the root of the problem was that it was still picking up an older version of SQLite elsewhere on the system.